# Information needed on two parameters in power setting GUID in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, power

A windows powerplan sets a number of behaviors of the system and these are enumerated as separate power setting GUIDs. For example

```
Power Setting GUID: 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0  (System unattended sleep timeout)
      GUID Alias: UNATTENDSLEEP
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000078
```

I cannot find any documentation on what the 'Current AC Power Setting Index' or 'Current DC Power Setting Index' do.

Comment: AC power setting is a DIFFERENT parameter than maximum possible setting. Your answer was misleading.

Comment: these docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/fine-tune-a-custom-power-plan-technicalreference are from microsoft. They show for example setting brightness to 75 (hex 64) is set in the field Maximum Possible Setting. How does one set Current AC Power Setting? sorry if I misunderstood you.